# The non-alphabetic problem in Vigenere problem set

Tags: c, cs50

I just have done with Vigenere problem in CS50, but still, there's one wrong only, the non-alphabetic characters, when you write in plaintext anything without spaces, comma, any non-alphabetic, the program will run well, but if you wrote any non-alphabetic character, like space, the next character will take the wrong key, this my code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>



int main(int argc, string argv[])
{    



    // Make sure there is a command-line argment
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Variables
    int key[strlen(argv[1])];
    string plaintext;


    // Make sure the comman-line argment is Alphabets then make the key


    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
    {

        if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Error 2\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (islower(argv[1][i]))
        {
            key[i] = argv[1][i] - 'a';
        }

        else if (isupper(argv[1][i]))
        {
            key[i] = argv[1][i] - 'A';
        }  
    }





    // Ask the user to write the message
    plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");



    // Make sure the plaintext doesn't equal NULL
    if (plaintext != NULL)
    {


        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n ; i++)
        {

            // Print in slower case
            if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key[i % strlen(argv[1])])  - 'a') % 26) + 'a');
            }

            // Print in upper case      
            else if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] + key[i % strlen(argv[1])])  - 'A') % 26) + 'A');
            }

            // Print the non alphabetic 
            else if (!isalpha(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
            }


        }           
        // Print a new line 
        printf("\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: If the key contains the letter `a` or `A`, then `strlen(argv[1])` is not going to work properly.  You need to record the length of the key before you hack it. It's fine to do the hacking as long as you realize the consequences of your hacking.

Comment: You should post the input you give the program, the output you get and the expected output

Comment: Guys I just followed the hints included the problem set in cs50 site, so the only problem when there's non-alphabetic in the plaintext, by the way, the key should be as a command-line argument.

Comment: You're probably not supposed to advance the key when you encounter a non-alphabetic character. So using `i` as the index into the key won't work, because `i` increments for every character, alphabetic or not.

Comment: user3386109 alright, so what should I do to make it works well?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are using the same index for the plaintext and the key in this
 `for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n ; i++)` loop. The key will advance one position every time plaintext does. Obviously that is not what you want. You need to manage the key index independently of the plaintext index within that loop.

Suggest you rewatch [the walkthrough](https://docs.cs50.net/2017/fall/psets/2/vigenere/vigenere.html#walkthrough) and perhaps write out an example much the way Zamyla does the panda example.  And it's never too soon to learn how to use [debug50](https://docs.cs50.net/2016/fall/notes/2/week2.html#debugging).  If I recall correctly, there is a short for it in Week 2.

[CS50x has a stack forum](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to questions and answers about CS50x and the psets.

Comment: I've just sent my solution and I got my score "85%" But I just need to know how to fix it, so can you please write it? I mean can you write the code to make it works well?